# If $A\setminus C \subseteq A\setminus B$, then $B \subseteq C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove disprove this statement:

$$\text{if }A\setminus C \subseteq A\setminus B\;\Rightarrow\; B \subseteq C$$

My take: let

$$x \in A\setminus C\;\Rightarrow\;x \in A  \wedge x \notin C$$
By the definition of subset: $x \in A  \wedge x \notin B$
which means that there is $x$ that $x \notin B,C$
which means there is an element that is not present in b and C, thus B can't be subset of C.

Am I right?

Comment: this is hard to follow.  Clearly if, say, $B=C$ then the desired inclusion is possible. Or if $B=\emptyset$, $C=A$.  The problem, therefore, isn't to show that you can't have $B\subseteq C$ (since you clearly can) but to ask whether you *must* have $B\subseteq C$.

Comment: Showing that two sets don't contain an element does not imply that one can't be the subset of the other.

Comment: Disproving that statement means coming up with a counterexample—three sets $A,B,C$ where $A\setminus C\subseteq A\setminus B$ and $B\not\subseteq C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is wrong. As a simple counter-example, consider $A=\varnothing$ then $A\setminus C\subseteq A\setminus B$ is true for any $B, C.$ In particular, for those with $B\not\subseteq C.$

Comment: Wow, how did I not see that?! This is beautiful explanation, thank a lot!

Comment: No worries, these things happen :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is false : start from $B$ not included in $C$, and choose $A$ in order that $A\setminus B$ included in  $A\setminus B$. You will see there is a lot of choices for $A$!

The fact that $A$ appears in the assumption, but not in the conclusion, could have alerted you.